# Martians and Jovians

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, queueing-theory

In how many ways can five distinct Martians and eight distinct Jovians wait in line if no two Martians stand together?

Comment: Please add what your thoughts on the problem are, so that people may give relevant help without telling you what you already know.

Comment: I suspect that it would be easier to find the universe then subtract from it the number of ways two Martians can be found next to one another.

Comment: /offtopic: Jovians?  Are they from Jupiter? `:P`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a lineup of $8$ letters $J$ like this:
$$J \qquad J \qquad J \qquad J \qquad J \qquad J \qquad J \qquad J \qquad$$
There are $7$ gaps between $J$'s that we could slip an $M$ into, plus the $2$ "endgaps," for a total of $9$ places.

So **places** for the Martians can be chosen in $\binom{9}{5}$ ways. Multiply by $8!5!$ because these are distinct individuals. So once we have chosen the places for the Jovians, and the places for the Martians, we can insert the Jovians in $8!$ orders, and for each way we can insert the Martians in $5!$ different orders.

Comment: So then there are $\begin{pmatrix}9\\5\end{pmatrix}\cdot 8!\cdot 5!$ variations?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It simplifies a lot, to $(9)(8)(7)(6)(8!)$.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: In the skeleton $_J_J_J_J_J_J_J_J_$, where each J is a Jovian, the $5$ Martians must occupy $5$ different blanks.